# how to compare slopes linear regression

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

How to compare the slope of multiple regressions?

[image]

As you can see the slope is not comparable. The slope in graphic 3 is clearly flatter than graphic 1 but the slope value is much higher.

Or is there a better measure for the steepness of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of linear regression is exactly what it is supposed to be.

```
y=mx+c
```

The `m` slope gives the steepness of the regression line. There is no "better measure for the steepness of the line". This should be clear with the mathematics behind the equation of a straight line.

---

**The issue you are facing here is that of axis scaling. Each of your above charts has a different y-axis scale.** It's obvious why you are unable to visually compare the slopes of your regression lines. You are comparing apples to oranges in this case. If you visually compare a line drawn in different y ranges then you end up misinterpreting what the slope is.

> In short, You are visually comparing the slope between chart 1 which has y-axis from 14750 to 16500 against the slope of chart 3 which ranges from 4000 to 18000 which doesn't make any sense. It's like comparing apples to oranges

You need to fix the x and y-axis ranges (set them to a fixed value, say 0-20000) for y-axis and then you should be able to see that the slope values are exactly comparable and visually intuitive.

Use the following to set axis limits -

```
plt.xlim(0, 175)
plt.ylim(0, 20000)
```

Comment: ohh,  yeah obvious error right there! thanks for helping anyways!